# GestureRecognization like functionality for iPhone 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, photos, zooming

Is there any way we can add the same functionality like Gesture recognization available for ios 4.0 + in iPhone 3.1.3

Please help with some links or codes available as i am unable to find it.

Also please inform is it really possible to do such smooth zoom+rotate in iphone 3.1.3
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but you have to implement it all yourself. There was an example and some sample code of the "old" way to do it at WWDC. [Go here to see the WWDC session videos and slides](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/)

Once you sign in and launch iTunes, click on "Application Framework" and check out session 120 - Simplify Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers.  Download the slides and video. There should be some sample code in there.  Apparently there was a more in-depth example of this @ the 2009 WWDC, but I wasn't there, but maybe you can find it on apple's developer site